# PowerShell ForEach-Object parameters

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to use the [`Get-RemoteProgram` script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4) to list of installed programs on remote computers.

Not only do I want to capture the remote program list but also the version which is straight forward for a single system.

```
RemoteProgram -ComputerName remotecomputername -Property DisplayVersion,VersionMajor
```

```
ProgramName                                                 ComputerName        DisplayVersion VersionMajor
-----------                                                 ------------        -------------- ------------
System Center Endpoint Protection                           remotecomputername  4.7.214.0                 4
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) remotecomputername  10.0.50903                4
Synaptics Pointing Device Driver                            remotecomputername  18.0.7.34                18
```

However, when I loop this across multiple systems I lose the `DisplayVersion` and `MajorVersion` fields completely.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\computerlist.txt | ForEach-Object -Begin {RemoteProgram} -Process {RemoteProgram -ComputerName $_ -Property DisplayVersion,VersionMajor}
```

```
ProgramName                                                ComputerName
-----------                                                ------------
System Center Endpoint Protection                          remotecomputer
Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package - SE (x64) remotecomputer
Mozilla Firefox 57.0.2 (x64 en-US)                         remotecomputer
Mozilla Maintenance Service                                remotecomputer
```

Comment: `RemoteProgram` is not a standard PowerShell command, so you'll have to include its implementation to get help.

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4

Comment: Have you tried piping it to `Format-List *`? Just curious if you see the "missing" parameters that way.

Comment: OMG That worked! Thank you! So do you think it I export it to CSV the fields will show? Havent tried that yet.

Comment: Yeah it should work (_without_ the `Format-List` command); see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of PowerShell's output formatting.

When an object is returned, you get the full object and all of its properties.

When you try to *display* an object without instructions, PowerShell does its best to display it appropriately. That means it will decide which properties to show, whether to display them as a table or list, etc.

You can override how its *displayed* with `Format-*` commands, but for the purposes of *using* the objects, all the information is there.

That means if you pipe it to something like `Export-Csv`, it will use all the properties even if you aren't seeing them in a normal display.

If you want to *see them* specifically, use a `Format-*` command, but again those are for display only; don't send the out of those to other commands.